# Getting Null Pointer error while trying to test with spy

Tags: java, mockito, spy

I have a class (A) that contains an Autowired dependency of another Class(B), which in turn has an Autowired dependency on another class C.

I am trying to write test cases using Mockito and using spy annotation for the dependencies. I am getting Null Pointer Error while spying to class C.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ATest {

    @InjectMocks
    A a = new A();

    @Spy
    private B b;

    @Spy
    private C c;
}
```

```
@Service
public class B {

    @Autowired
    private C c;

public void doSomethinf(){
    c.doSomething();
   }
}
```

```
@Service
public class C {
public void doSomething(){}
}
```

How can I perform this unit test from class A?

Comment: Try using @Mock

Comment: With @Mock, I will have to write the implementation within my test case and I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think firstly you should define class A which injects B and C as its class members.
Then create another class to do testing.

```
public class A {
    @Autowired
    private B b;

    @Autowired
    private C c;
}
```

You need to separate testing target class definition and its testing class.

```
public class ATest {
    @InjectMocks
    A a = new A();

    @Spy
    private B b;

    @Spy
    private C c;

    @Test    
    pblic void test() {
        // do some stuffs
    }
}
```